# Can't add capabilities in Xcode after update Xcode 15

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have a problem since I installed xcode 15. In my existing project I had several capabilities active like Push Notification Apple Pay or Domains, now everything is gone except Background Modes, when I try to add it again it doesn't work, none of the mentioned, does anyone have a similar problem or a solution. I just recently paid the $99 for the dev account, so it can't be that.

[image]

**Possible Solution:**

I was able to solve the problem. In my case, something went wrong during the update and the Runner.entitlements file was damaged. I came up with the solution because if you start a new test project and it is possible to add capabilities, then it has something to do with the project itself.

Comment: I had the same issue, restarted Xcode and also toggled the "Automatically manage signing" off and on again and in the end I was able to add new Capabilities